# Catch exceptions without a try block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a lot of custom exceptions that I'm throwing in a specific cases in the code, and I'd like to have one catch block at the bottom of the method to handle them all.

All the exceptions are children of the Exception class CribbageException, so I'd like to have:

```
public void myMethod(){
     if (whatever){
          throw new CardException();
     }
     if (something else){
         throw new InvalidCardException();
     }
     if (scenario 3){
          throw new TwoCardsException();
     }
     catch (CribbageException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

But I'm getting a catch without try error.

Is there any way to use this type of exception handling?

Comment: `catch without try` Say that out loud a few times.

Comment: Just add the `try` block, as the error suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap all the `throw`s inside a single `try`.

```
public void myMethod(){
    try {
        if (whatever){
             throw new CardException();
        }
        if (something else){
            throw new InvalidCardException();
        }
        if (scenario 3){
            throw new TwoCardsException();
        }
    }
    catch (CribbageException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```